# Between you and me

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, video-games

```
 ⬛⬛

⬜⬜⬜⬜ air pollution
⬜⬜⬜⬜ wildebeests
⬜⬜⬜⬜ bullets
⬜⬜⬜⬜ whine
⬜⬜⬜⬜ cozy
```

Your final answer should be an appropriate image.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The image you are looking for is something like this:

> [image: Image the OP is hoping to see]
>
>  which is a 20-pixel, 2-colour representation of one of the characters from the online game **[AMONG US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Among_Us)**:
>
>  [image: Among Us character]

How do we get this? First resolve the 5 clues as follows:

> **S M O G** = air pollution
>  **G N U S** = wildebeests
>  **A M M O** = bullets
>  **M O A N** = whine
>  **S N U G** = cozy

Note that these answers...

> ...only use letters from the set {A, G, M, N, O, S, U}. Fittingly, **AMONG US** is a perfect anagram of this letter set.  We also know we're working on the right lines here since the title - 'Between you and me' - is synonymous with 'among us', and there is a [video-games](/questions/tagged/video-games) tag.

Now look at the very first line of the puzzle. This conveys two pieces of information to us:

> (i) That something connected to the answer is two words of 5 and then 2 letters (i.e. 'AMONG US'), and
>
>  (ii) That we should consider *shading* the letters of our 4x5 answer grid in two different colours: the letters that make up the first word in any colour we choose (indicated by the question mark) and the letters of the second word in black. This produces the image seen at the top of this answer, and the puzzle is solved!
>
>  [image: Shading process]

Comment: Close, but I'm looking for a more specific image, perhaps one that has rot13(rknpgyl gjragl cvkryf)...

Comment: @IAmLucidNonsense Oh, I see what you want!

Comment: That shading looks sus.

Comment: Stiv was not The Impostor. 1 impostor remains.